# download diff file from websvn

Tags: svn, diff, websvn, review-board

Is there a way to generate a diff file (describes changes made in a specific commit transaction) using  [websvn](https://websvnphp.github.io) interface, and allow users to download it ?

I want to allow users to download such a diff from websvn, and upload it to to the  [reviewBoard](http://www.reviewboard.org/) (code review) application.

I know I can do something with svn command line,  but I need something that will work on the web, and since I have already websvn installed, I thought it will be reasonable to use it for such propose.

Comment: Sounds like a feature request for websvn. :)